# Access to variable from one controller in second controller in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I know there is a lot of threads about passing parameters, but I still don't understand.

I have `Main.fxml` stage with `MainController` class. In this class I create for example variable `int x = 5`. Then I click button on this stage which creates new stage with `SecondController` where I can modify this value. In `MainController` are setter and getter methods for `x` value. In `SecondController` I can get `x` value from `MainController` and edit it but in the end when I close second stage i try to set this edited value with new number by setter method from `MainController`. Then I close it stage and again open it this same way like first time. But I can't see new edited value, I see again this same which is created default.

Here is my `MainController` which is called `FirstController`:

```
public class FirstController {
    private int x = 5;

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    void click(ActionEvent event) {
        SecondController secondController = new SecondController();
        secondController.startSecondController(new Stage());
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize()
    {
        label.setText(Integer.toString(x));
    }

    //constructor
    public FirstController() {

    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

And here is my `SecondController` :

```
public class SecondController {
    @FXML
    private TextField testArea;

    private FirstController firstController;

    private int localX;

    //constructor
    public SecondController() {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("First.fxml"));
        try
        {
            loader.load();
            firstController = loader.getController();

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void startSecondController(Stage stage)
    {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("Second.fxml"));
        try
        {
            Pane pane = loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 300);
            stage.setTitle("Second Window");
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void click(ActionEvent event) {
        localX = Integer.parseInt(testArea.getText());
        firstController.setX(localX);
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize()
    {
        localX = firstController.getX();
        testArea.setText(Integer.toString(localX));
    }
}
```

I think describe of this problem is sufficient to understand this. Does anyone can give me example how to achieve my goal ?

Comment: I guess it's probably because there is an error in your code.

Comment: @James_D, I attached my code

Comment: This just looks identical to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40717499/send-object-to-controller-and-return-it-in-javafx). You have fundamental misunderstandings about the way the `FXMLLoader` works. Calling `load()` causes the `FXMLLoader` to create a *new instance* of the class specified by `fx:controller`. It doesn't magically give you a reference to the existing instance you want it to give you. It looks like you don't know - or have perhaps temporarily forgotten - the difference between a class and an object.

Answer (score 0):

I think a lot about that what @James_D said and I've done my code. That are results where controllers can communicate between each other:
`FirstController` class :

```
public class FirstController {

    private IntegerProperty x = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

    SecondController secondController;

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    void click(ActionEvent event) {
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("Second.fxml"));
        try
        {
            Pane pane = loader.load();
            secondController = loader.getController();
            secondController.setLocalX(x.getValue());
            secondController.setFirstController(this);
            Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 300);
            stage.setTitle("Second Window");
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize()
    {
        label.setText(Integer.toString(x.getValue()));
        x.addListener( observable -> {
            label.setText(Integer.toString(x.getValue()));
        });
    }

    //constructor
    public FirstController() {
        x.set(5);
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x.getValue();
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x.set(x);
    }
}
```

And `SecondController` which change `x` value from `FirstController`:

```
public class SecondController {
    @FXML
    private TextField testArea;

    private FirstController firstController;

    private int localX;

    public void setFirstController(FirstController firstController) {
        this.firstController = firstController;
    }


    public void setLocalX(int x)
    {
        localX = x;
        testArea.setText(Integer.toString(localX));
    }


    @FXML
    void click(ActionEvent event) {
        localX = Integer.parseInt(testArea.getText());
        firstController.setX(localX);
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize()
    {
        testArea.setText(Integer.toString(localX));
    }
}
```

Is this way good? Or better try to use injection by `afterburner.fx` framework ?